# How to rename files removing everything up to the second or third occurence of a character?

Tags: linux, terminal, rename

I have a list of files, in different folders, named like

```
aaaaaa_bb_cccc_ddddd_ee.jpg
```

In some of them, I need to remove everything up to the second _, so they become

```
cccc_ddddd_ee.jpg
```

In others (already in a separate folder), I need to remove everything up to the third _

```
ddddd_ee.jpg
```

I know commands such as rename, which use some REGEX, but I don't know the exact expression for this case. How can I do that on Linux terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Perl Rename utility,

```
$ ls
aaaaaa_bb_cccc_ddddd_ee.jpg
$ rename -n 's/([^_]*_){2}//' *
rename(aaaaaa_bb_cccc_ddddd_ee.jpg, cccc_ddddd_ee.jpg)
$ rename -n 's/([^_]*_){3}//' *
rename(aaaaaa_bb_cccc_ddddd_ee.jpg, ddddd_ee.jpg)
```

The `-n` flag tells Rename to output what it would do. If you remove `-n`, the
modifications will be applied.

The `*` will expand to every file in the current directory. In the example above,
there was only one file, but Rename can operate on multiple files in a single run,
in which case `*` is faster instead of a shell loop.

`s/([^_]*_){2}//` means: `s`ubstitute every occurrence of the `([^_]*_){2}` regular expression in filenames by nothing. The regex means: any number of non-underscores `[^_]*` followed by a underscore `_` repeated twice.

Answer (score 3):

To eliminate everything up to the second _

```
rename -n 's/[^_]*[_][^_]*[_]//' *
```

To eliminate everything up to the third _

```
rename -n 's/[^_]*[_][^_]*[_][^_]*[_]//' *
```

Remove the `-n` to effectively change the filenames, and not just test.

Comment: Nice to see you came up with a solution! Just a note: It is good to quote the regex so as to prevent the shell from expanding the `*` as globs (highly unlikely in this case, though, you would have to have a very weirdly named file for that to happen.).

Comment: @Quasímodo Good to know. Thank you!